# What can I do if i need to implement a TextFieldDelegate on a ViewController that already has a TableViewDelegate?

Tags: objective-c, protocols

My ViewController looks like this:

```
@interface EventsViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
```

because in my view i have a TableView and I need to manage it.
But I also have a TextField, and I have to manage it as well.

How can I do it? Is implementing more than one delegate not a wise choice, right? I heard it may cause problems.

Comment: Look at what you posted. You are already conforming to two protocols. So your question is really about adding a 3rd. I have one class that conforms to a dozen. It's fine.

Answer (score 4):

Just add it to the list, there is no problem whatsoever

```
@interface EventsViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate,UITextFieldDelegate>
```

Comment: I've heard that may cause problems. Is there another method to manage my TextField?

Comment: @Ales I don't see why it would cause any problems : delegates are made for this kind of things. I don't know where you read that this may cause problems, but it won't.

Comment: That won't cause any problems. The delegate declarations just tell the compiler that your class adheres to the protocols listed. In this case, you'll adhere to UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, and UITextFieldDelegate. This just means that your class will implement and required methods from those protocols and can implement and optional methods from them. There's no limit to how many protocols a class can implement.

Comment: The better solution is to remove all of these protocols from the .h file and add them to a class extension in the .m file. There is no reason to announce these implementation details to the world.

Answer (score 0):

No, it won't cause a problem/ If it cause a problem why did you have both `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` instead of one ?